# Full page overlay on Windows Phone 7+

Tags: html, windows-phone-7, css

After several searches I can't find a solution to position an overlay on top of a page that works on the latest Windows Phones. This works for all modern browsers, but not Windows Phones.

**CSS**

```
html, body
{
    height: 100%;
}
div.overlay
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: gray;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="overlay">Centered?</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sAF5s/)

Comment: Is JavaScript or jQuery an option?

Comment: With JS i already know the solution. I need a clean CSS solution